# SELECT NOT IN two foreign keys from other table

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to find a `SELECT` query that returns all of **tableA.tba_id** that are not exists on tableB (note that are two different foreign keys - **tbb_tbAID1** and **tbb_tbAID2** between data.
[You can find DB Model here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7in6.png)

**What I can do so far**
*This only tests one column*

```
SELECT tba_id FROM tableA 
WHERE tba_id NOT IN
  (SELECT tbb_tbAID1 FROM tableB
  WHERE tbb_date > '$date2')
```

I get a MySQL error when trying to test on both foreign keys

> ## 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

**Query:**

```
SELECT tba_id FROM tableA 
WHERE tba_id NOT IN
  (SELECT tbb_tbAID1,tbb_tbAID2 FROM tableB
  WHERE tbb_date > '$date2')
```

**Try 2:**

```
SELECT tba_id FROM tableA 
WHERE tba_id NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM tableB
    WHERE (tba_id = tbb_tbAID1 OR tba_id = tbb_tbAID2)
  AND tbb_date > '$date2')
```

But gets more results than the first try (that suggests that it's extremely wrongly done)

**Try3:**

```
SELECT tba_id FROM tableA JOIN tableB ON tba_id!=tbb_tbAID1 AND tba_is!=tbb_tbAID2 WHERE tbb_data > '$data'
```

This results on enormous set of data, far away from first method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actually working query:

```
SELECT tba_id FROM tableA
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE (tba_id = tbb_tbAID1 OR tba_id = tbb_tbAID2) AND tbb_data > '$date')
```

On **Try2**, I replaced `SELECT 1` for `SELECT *` and delete that `WHERE tba_id NOT EXISTS` and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Make a join instead of the nested query, it is faster and more efficient as well.

```
SELECT tba_id FROM tableA JOIN tableB ON tba_id!=tbb_tbAID1 AND tba_is!=tbb_tbAID2
```

Comment: This do not completely answer my question, as I really tried with `JOIN` before (sorry for didn't mention it, question updated) and it does not select from tableB's `data`